# Why doesn't code after while loop execute when this C++ program is built and ran?

Tags: c++

There is a code block extracted from the book "C++ Primer" which when executed doesn't return the output displayed in the book:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  // currVal is the number we're counting; we'll read new values into val
  int currVal = 0, val = 0;
  // read first number and ensure that we have data to process
  if (std::cin >> currVal) {
    int cnt = 1; // store the count for the current value we're processing
    while (std::cin >> val) { // read the remaining numbers
      if (val == currVal) // if the values are the same
        ++cnt; // add 1 to cnt
      else { // otherwise, print the count for the previous value
        std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
        currVal = val; // remember the new value
        cnt = 1; // reset the counter
      }
    } // while loop ends here
  // remember to print the count for the last value in the file
  std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
} // outermost if statement ends here
return 0;
}
```

When I execute this code in online compilers (such as https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/) or build and execute it locally on a Mac with input such as:

`1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3`

The output is:

```
1 occurs 2 times
2 occurs 3 times
```

instead of the expected:

```
1 occurs 2 times
2 occurs 3 times
3 occurs 4 times
```

I've tried pressing the "Return"/"Enter" key as well as Ctrl + D after entering the inputs, but neither approach works. How can I enter the inputs in a way that allows the program to print the desired output to the console?

Comment: Works here: https://godbolt.org/z/GoxPazadx Works locally in Windows too. The last line of output will not be printed until after you've sent EOF, perhaps that is throwing you off?

Comment: When entering manually you have to press **Ctrl + d** to indicate end-of-input by generating a manual `EOF`. (**Ctrl+z** on windows). Pipe or just redirect from `stdin` using a bash herestring, e.g. `echo "1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3" | ./yourprog` or with bash `./yourprog <<< "1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3"`

Comment: The EOF was indeed the issue. The EOF (for example, Ctrl + D) should be pressed after the first two lines are printed to the console. Thanks to the both of you.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 1):

The author might have left out that you can give some invalid input such as a character to end of your list of numbers to end the while loop from reading more `int` values so instead passing

```
1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

and pressing enter, try

```
1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 a
```

and pressing enter